# What is #ifdef __OBJC__ doing and why libraries listed below?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, import, conditional-compilation

I believe the `#ifdef __OBJC__` directive is ensuring that I import the following class libraries for Objective-C only.  What is the purpose of listing the class libraries after the `ifdef` statement?  Doesn't this code example kinda defeat the purpose?

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <foundation/foundation.h>
#import <uikit/uikit.h>
#import <coredata/coredata.h>
#endif
</coredata/coredata.h></uikit/uikit.h></foundation/foundation.h>
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? The capitalization is all wonky and it looks like a directive must be missing.

Comment: `#import` does not import libraries, it imports headers.  The libraries (frameworks in this case) related to the headers are linked to elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is a superset of C (just like C++ is) and fairly often files from the different languages will be used in the same project and share headers, especially the prefix header.  The `#ifdef __OBJC__`, like `#ifdef __cplusplus`, lets you include (or `#import` for Objective-C) headers for only the appropriate language.

The same header included in .c, .cpp, and .m files (with default compiler settings) would only have `__OBJ__` defined for the .m files.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in that code if you are using Objective C it will import those 3 libraries

```
#import <foundation/foundation.h>
#import <uikit/uikit.h>
#import <coredata/coredata.h>
```

The purpose of that if, is to not import them unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

They are listed after the `#endif` just as a reminder, so it makes the code easier to read. Otherwise you'd have to look up above to see what the `#endif` was ending.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is done is so that this code can still be compatible with regular C code that may want to use the functionality in that C file (at least that's what it looks like to me). By including those libraries only when OBJC is defined it ensures that the libraries are ONLY imported when you are compiling for objective c and not for standard C.